# Flutter text not showing in center vertically and horizontally

Tags: flutter

I need to show my text on the center of the container. Try to give alignment to container widget and text widget but don't know why it's not showing in the center vertically.

Here is my code

```
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            height: stackHeight * 0.5,
            width: stackWidth,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Would you like to take coffe',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      )
                    )
                 )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the column:

```
             Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                            'Would you like to take cock with sand',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          )))
                    ],
                  ),
```

And if you don't need it:

```
Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Would you like to take cock with sand',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Thanks its centered now

Comment: @ShahnazRaheem please mark as correct, and also look at the updated asnwer, second approach is better if you don't need column